How to center text views in a custom progress bar in jetpack compose
I'm trying to create a custom progress bar in Compose, where each step is represented by a dot, and beneath each dot, there's a text label. However, I'm having trouble aligning the text labels so that they are properly centerred under each dot.
This is what i'm trying to achieve:

Here is my current implementation and how it looks:

data class Step(val title: String = "") {}

StepsProgressView(
     steps = listOf(Step("text"),Step("something"),Step("some"),Step("DD"),Step("Ssss cccc")),
     completedIndex = 2
)

@Composable
fun StepsProgressView(
    steps: List<Step>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    lineWidth: Dp = 1.dp,
    completedIndex: Int = 2
) {
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                val width = drawContext.size.width
                val height = drawContext.size.height

                val yOffset = height / 2
                val itemWidth = width / steps.size

                var startOffset = itemWidth / 2
                var endOffset = startOffset

                val barWidth = lineWidth.toPx()
                repeat(steps.size - 1) { index ->
                    endOffset += itemWidth

                    drawLine(
                        brush = SolidColor(if (index < completedIndex) Color.Blue else Color.Gray),
                        start = Offset(startOffset, yOffset),
                        end = Offset(endOffset, yOffset),
                        strokeWidth = barWidth
                    )
                    startOffset = endOffset
                }
            }

            Row(
                Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            ) {
                repeat(steps.size) { index ->
                    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                        // last index image
                        if (index == steps.lastIndex)
                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(id = androidx.biometric.R.drawable.fingerprint_dialog_fp_icon),
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
                                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                            )
                        // circles box
                        else
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(12.dp)
                                    .drawBehind {
                                        drawCircle(
                                            color =
                                              if (index <= completedIndex) Color.Blue
                                              else Color.Gray
                                        )
                                    },
                                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                                content = {})
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.height(8.dp))

        Row(
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
        ) {
            steps.forEachIndexed { index, step ->
                Text(
                    text = step.title,
                    style = TextStyle(
                          color = 
                             if (steps.indexOf(step) <= completedIndex) Color.Blue 
                             else Color.Gray,
                          fontSize = 13.sp,
                          textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentWidth()
                        .weight(1f)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

The issue I'm facing is that the text labels beneath the dots are not perfectly aligned in the center. I want each text label to be directly centered below its corresponding dot.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

As it is now, your code is not quite reproducible. Your HelpText Composable is not included, and we don't know where drawContext is coming from. Your approach using the weight Modifier looks fine, the texts should be evenly distributed. I think the actual question you are facing is how to make the first dot of the progress bar being drawn  above thee center of the first text. Or, the other way round, _how to specify the left padding of your texts Row so that the first text is centered below the first dot of the progress bar. Also, could you edit your post and include a screenshot?

'HelpText' just a custom text composable, fixed it.
'drawContext' is accessible from the Canvas scope.
And the question i'm facing is how to make the last text views from the progress bar drawn centered below the dots, because they are the ones that misalign, partly because the last index is an image twice as big as the other dots. I will edit my post and upload a screenshot in the morning

The problem is caused by the last image being twice as big as the other dots. When i align them to be the same size, the texts align perfectly

The problem is that your last index image is larger than the other circles. That messes with the arrangement in your Row that depends on weight(1f) to distribute the space evenly.
One way to solve that is to make the last index image measure with the same size as the other circles and then paint the image with the desired size nonetheless:
// last index image
if (index == steps.lastIndex)
    Box(modifier = Modifier.size(12.dp)) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.barImage),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.requiredSize(24.dp),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
// circles box
else
    ...

You might need to add an additional padding to the Row so that this larger-than-expected image still fits.

Thank you so much, I just got the chance to try it!
